# HttpModule only on specific MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, httpmodule

I have a custom `IHttpModule` that I would like to only work on a specific route.

For example : `http://example.com/HandleAzureTask`

I want this module to only be invoked/handled on the `/HandleAzureTask` route.

Since this is not a controller, I can't really set the `[Authorize]` attribute on it; how can I force it only to be invoked/handled if user is authenticated?

I am on ASP.NET MVC 4 and currently have my module added to web.config as such:

```xml
<modules>
  <remove name="AzureWebDAVModule" />
  <add name="AzureWebDAVModule" type="VMC.WebDAV.Azure.Module.AzureWebDAVModule, VMC.WebDAV.Azure.Module" />
</modules>
```

Comment: I would suggest to create custom route constrain for this route...

Comment: What is your HttpModule doing? If you are using this module only on this ASP.NET MVC application you could consider rewriting it as an action filter.

Comment: I have a WebDav server IHttpModule that handles interactions between office applications and Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: Is the requirement to keep that code as a module?  If not, I would suggest to refactor this into a controller/action method so you could take advantage of the MVC Authorize. Then, use the routes collection accordingly.

Comment: @dotsa let me know if you are thinking to share this module. Its just what I'm looking for to satisfy an client's requirement.

Comment: @darwindave this question was in part due to a project i was working on. You can see it here: https://mvc4webdav.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5):

HttpModules are called on every request (HttpHandlers, instead, can be filtered). If you just want to perform your task only on the selected route, you can do the following:

Set up a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AzureWebDAVRoute",
    url: "HandleAzureTask",
    // notice the enableHandler parameter
    defaults: new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction", enableHandler = true }
);
```

On your module:

```
public class AzureWebDAVModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        // you can't directly access Request object here, it will throw an exception
        context.PostAcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(context_PostAcquireRequestState);
    }

    void context_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;
        RouteData routeData = context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;

        if (routeData != null && routeData.Values["enableHandler"] != null)
        {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now your task will be performed on the selected route only. Please note that you need the parameter since you can't find the current route by name.

Comment: Luca, does this mean that i have to have an actual controller? If yes, do i set [authorize] tag on the controller? If not, how would i go about adding [authorize] tag to "HandleAzureTask" controller, at routing level through custom filter? So, basically HttpModule will still be called every time something is loaded, but will only act when routeData.Values["enableHandler"] != null. I use this for WebDav file storage, but actual files are stored in Azure Blob.

Comment: @dotsa The `[Authorize]` attribute will have little effect here, since the HttpModule will be called **anyway**. If you want to filter access to your module, you could add a `Request.IsAuthenticated` condition. The problem is that you are using an HttpModule and such components are integrated into the ASP.NET pipeline. Please note that [HttpHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903367(v=vs.71).aspx), unlike modules, can support a path parameter.

Comment: What is the necessity of the controller in this scenario. I can filter the url parameter in IHttpModule as well, and if it contains the "HandleAzureTask" then handle will do its thing. Am I missing something? Or by using Controller we are able to add [Authorize] attribute?

Comment: @dotsa in this case, i think the controller and action method is irrelevant. you module code that actually executes (inside that if) needs to overwrite response content.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a ordinary folder namned /HandleAzureTask and put a seperate web.config inside that folder with the module registration.

Then the module will run for all request in that folder.

To get the authorization to work you can also set the authorization element in the web.config to disallow *