# controller specific iis logging with ASP.NET MVC in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I want to log visits only for some controllers (or routes) as it was possible with classic ASP.NET pages by checking/unchecking the 'log visits' checkbox in IIS.

Does anyone know if this is possible somehow? A solution without a custom logging component would be fantastic! Please share your knowledge, if you know how ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseController which the controllers that you want to record data for inherit from. Then create an ActionFilter which overrides the OnActionExecuted method and apply it to the base controller. Something like this..

```
public class ActionExecutedFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    UnitOfWork unitOfWork= new UnitOfWork();

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filter)
    {
        Transaction tran = new Transaction();
        tran.Controller = filter.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        tran.ActionName = filter.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        tran.User = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        tran.Date = DateTime.Now;

        unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Insert(tran);
        unitOfWork.Save();
    }
}
```

This will save to a database table called Transactions information for every time a action method is called on that controller, recording the user, controller and action method name. Obviously I just typed in the UnitOfWork method of saving to the database, you can just plug in whichever method you like. I usually keep these methods in a filters folder, add a using statement then add it to the controller like so;

```
[ActionExecutedFilter]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
}
```

Again, just make all the controller you wish to record data from inherit the BaseController.

You could also use something like Log4Net, but I find just doing it this way gets what I need. Whatever you think yourself.

http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/logging-in-mvc-part-4-log4net/

Answer (score 0):

> A solution without a custom logging component would be fantastic!

Apart from basic IIS diagnostic logs, I cannot think of any ASP.Net MVC specific Logging features in IIS.

One simple solution what I want to offer is to write a **HttpModule**. In the HttpModule you can log the requests. Also if you want to have control on what to log and what not to, then based on Routes you can make that happen in HttpModule. Advantage with HttpModule is it is easy to plug in and also easy to remove.

[Make HttpModule work only on certain routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798828/httpmodule-only-on-specific-mvc-route)

When it comes to logging itself, you can have your own custom logic to database or to log file. But you can opt for [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) or [Log4Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8245/A-Brief-Introduction-to-the-log4net-logging-librar) or [Enterprise Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx)